# Error when trying to up docker containers

Tags: php, api, docker, nginx, api-platform.com

I'm on this issue since 2 days, trying a lot of solutions found on internet but no one resolved my case... I'm frustrated, I hope someone could help me.

I'm on Linux, and I don't really understand anything with server ports, hosts, etc.

It seems that this project uses API Platform, I don't know if it could help or not.

I can't figure out how to launch this project I just received. I have an issue when launching containers (docker-compose up) :

```
Error thrown while running command "doctrine:schema:update -f". Message: "An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused

Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
php_1          |    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
php_1          | could not connect to server: Address not available
php_1          |    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
php_1          |    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"
```

**It seems that the container can't communicate with the DB container. But I don't know exactly what to do to solve this.**

There is several containers in the docker-composer.yml :

```
    version: '3'

services:
    php:
        build:
            context: ./api
        depends_on:
            - db
        env_file:
            - ./api/.env
        # Comment out these volumes in production
        volumes:
            - ./api:/srv/api:rw,cached
            # If you develop on Linux, comment out the following volumes to just use bind-mounted project directory from host
            - /srv/api/var/
            - /srv/api/var/cache/
            - /srv/api/var/logs/
            - /srv/api/var/sessions/

    api:
        build:
            context: ./api
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.nginx
        depends_on:
            - php
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        volumes:
            - ./api/public:/srv/api/public:ro

    cache-proxy:
        build:
            context: ./api
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.varnish
        depends_on:
            - api
        # Comment out this volume in production
        volumes:
            - ./api/docker/varnish/conf:/etc/varnish:ro
        ports:
            - "8081:80"

    db:
        # In production, you may want to use a managed database service
        image: postgres:9.6-alpine
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_DB=api
            - POSTGRES_USER=api-platform
            # You should definitely change the password in production
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=!ChangeMe!
        volumes:
            - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
            # You may use a bind-mounted host directory instead, so that it is harder to accidentally remove the volume and lose all your data!
            # - ./docker/db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"

    client:
        # Use a static website hosting service in production
        # See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment
        build:
            context: ./client
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        env_file:
            - ./client/.env
        volumes:
            - ./client:/usr/src/client:rw,cached
            - /usr/src/client/node_modules
        ports:
            - "80:3000"

    h2-proxy:
        # Don't use this proxy in prod
        build:
            context: ./h2-proxy
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        depends_on:
            - client
            - api
            - cache-proxy
        ports:
            - "443:443"
            - "444:444"
            - "8443:8443"
            - "8444:8444"

volumes:
    db-data: {}
```

**Dockerfile** :

```
    ARG PHP_VERSION=7.2
ARG ALPINE_VERSION=3.7
FROM php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm-alpine${ALPINE_VERSION}

RUN apk add --no-cache \
        git

ARG APCU_VERSION=5.1.11
RUN set -xe \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        $PHPIZE_DEPS \
        icu-dev \
        postgresql-dev \
        zlib-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) \
        intl \
        pdo_pgsql \
        zip \
    && pecl install \
        apcu-${APCU_VERSION} \
    && docker-php-ext-enable --ini-name 20-apcu.ini apcu \
    && docker-php-ext-enable --ini-name 05-opcache.ini opcache \
    && runDeps="$( \
        scanelf --needed --nobanner --format '%n#p' --recursive /usr/local/lib/php/extensions \
            | tr ',' '\n' \
            | sort -u \
            | awk 'system("[ -e /usr/local/lib/" $1 " ]") == 0 { next } { print "so:" $1 }' \
    )" \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .api-phpexts-rundeps $runDeps \
    && apk del .build-deps

RUN apk add --no-cache freetype libpng libjpeg-turbo freetype-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev && \
  docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    --with-gd \
    --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ \
    --with-png-dir=/usr/include/ \
    --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ && \
  NPROC=$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo 2>/dev/null || 1) && \
  docker-php-ext-install -j${NPROC} gd exif && \
  apk del --no-cache freetype-dev libpng-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
COPY docker/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

# https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-allow-superuser
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1
RUN composer global require "hirak/prestissimo:^0.3" --prefer-dist --no-progress --no-suggest --classmap-authoritative

RUN apk add  --no-cache ffmpeg

WORKDIR /srv/api

# Prevent Symfony Flex from generating a project ID at build time
ARG SYMFONY_SKIP_REGISTRATION=1

# Prevent the reinstallation of vendors at every changes in the source code
COPY composer.json composer.lock ./
RUN composer install --prefer-dist --no-dev --no-autoloader --no-scripts --no-progress --no-suggest \
    && composer clear-cache

COPY . ./

RUN mkdir -p var/cache var/logs var/sessions \
    && composer dump-autoload --classmap-authoritative --no-dev \
    && chown -R www-data var

COPY docker/php/docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint"]
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

**.env file** :

```
APP_ENV=dev
APP_SECRET=!ChangeMe!
TRUSTED_PROXIES=10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16
TRUSTED_HOSTS=localhost,api
DATABASE_URL=pgsql://api-platform:!ChangeMe!@localhost/api
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=^https?://localhost:?[0-9]*$
VARNISH_URL=http://cache-proxy
JWT_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH=config/jwt/private.pem
JWT_PUBLIC_KEY_PATH=config/jwt/public.pem
JWT_PASSPHRASE=symfony
JWT_TOKEN_TTL=null
MAILER_URL=gmail://email:password@localhost?
MAILER_FROM=user@example.com
CLIENT_MAGIC_LINK_URL=https://localhost/login
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID=433898047056774
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET=90ac80e435405a2ffeaab8a242981152
AUTH_API_KEY=123456789
ADMIN_PWD=$2y$13$vqd7AMd0A5eetDT00qLd2OkGG8T9UJ1gLsD2huOhk3iRwGCBqR3iu
```

I don't know if you guys needs something more. Just tell me what you need.

Thanks a lot...

Comment: It looks like the php container (running your api) is attempting to connect to the MySQL database using the loopback address. This won't work as the database is its own container (db) so any references to the loopback address in your api config need changing to reference the db container.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the actual error message (not a screen shot of a terminal) and reduce what you have to a [mcve]?  As @mtt_g suggests those three lines sound like a PHP connection error but without having the PHP code, the environment file, or the Dockerfile it’s hard to cast more than a guess (though “you’re misusing `localhost`” is a pretty strong guess).

Comment: @DavidMaze I never configured a Docker and never configured any server so the docker-compose looks like hieroglyph. I edited to put the Dockerfile and the environment file.

mtt_g I understand what you say but I don't know where are the references you tell. So I don't know where to change the address

Comment: you may have look on [already packaged PHP env in docker](https://laradock.io/introduction/) whitch are build to not reinvent the wheel

Comment: tl;dr your backend should not connect to localhost but to `db` instead! This is the host name (container name) of the database. You need to change the `DATABASE_URL` env variable to reflect that.

Comment: @emix Thank you ! It successed to connect the database when changing the DATABASE_URL In environment file !

Comment: Np. Please mark my answer as answer then if you may :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `db` as the database host, not `localhost` in the `DATABASE_URL` application env.